# Excel VBA copy data in a range for every 100000 rows and paste to a different sheet until all the data has been copied in the range

Tags: vba, dynamic, count, row, offset

I would like to copy data in a sheet (Sheet1) to another sheet (Sheet2). However I would this to be done in blocks of 100,000 rows and continue until all the data in Sheet1 has been copied to Sheet2. I've toyed with offsets, rows.count etc, but I cannot get it to work. Any help is much appreciated.

```
Sub MyRow()
Dim iRow
Dim Z As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Z = 1 To 8
    Sheets("sheet2").Range("A2:E100000" & Z).Copy Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:E")
Next Z

End Sub
```

Comment: Please write the code that you have tried

Comment: Thanks for you response. Unfortunately my code is not worth putting on here. I simply dont know where to start. It is as simple as copying information within range ( inclusive of 100000 rows, column 10), then pasting that information to another sheet and then resuming to the next 100000 rows

Comment: This is not separate 100k rows each time. First, when Z=1, the result of `"A2:E100000" & Z` is `A2:E1000001`. Then, when Z=2, the result is `A2:E1000002`, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to reuse as much of your code as possible. I think this might be what you want.

```
Sub MyRow()
Dim Z As Integer
Dim lastRow As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

lastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
For Z = 1 To WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(lastRow / 100000, 0)
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:E100000").Offset((Z - 1) * 100000).Copy _
      Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Offset((Z - 1) * 100000)
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. this is very helpful!